# Fast Query mysql between 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Help me guys, how to make my query faster

```
SELECT b.id_barang
     , b.nama
     , ( SELECT SUM(qty) FROM baru_kasir WHERE k.id_barang = b.id_barang GROUP BY b.id_barang LIMIT 1) 
     - ( SELECT SUM(qty) FROM barang_gdg_pesan WHERE barang_gdg_pesan.id_barang = b.id_barang GROUP BY b.id_barang LIMIT 1 ) AS STOCK

  FROM baru_barang b 
 WHERE stts = 'AKTIF' 
 ORDER 
    BY b.nama ASC;
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the table structure  - all as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

It will almost certainly be more efficient to `JOIN` to tables of the `SUM`s rather than running two subqueries for every row:

```
SELECT bb.id_barang,
       bb.nama, 
       bk.qty - bgp.qty AS stock
FROM baru_barang bb
JOIN (SELECT id_barang, SUM(qty) AS qty
      FROM baru_kasir 
      GROUP BY id_barang) bk ON bk.id_barang= bb.id_barang
JOIN (SELECT id_barang, SUM(qty) AS qty
      FROM barang_gdg_pesan
      GROUP BY id_barang) bgp ON bgp.id_barang = bb.id_barang 
WHERE stts='AKTIF'
ORDER BY bb.nama ASC;
```

Ensuring that you have indexes on the `id_barang` columns in each table will also help performance.

Comment: Thanks,,
but this get error
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'bk.id_barang' in 'on clause'
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: @CeceSyamsulHadi sorry, I couldn't test the query as I didn't have any sample data. I've made a correction which should solve that problem.